# How to prevent inherited classes instances

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to force any class not to be able to create a new instance if it inherits a specific base class, so how this base class should look like?

Comment: A specific or any? If the answer is any you could use the `sealed` keyword.

Comment: then whats the point of inheriting from that base class? give an example of what you want to do

Comment: This is nonsense. Try to ask it better, with an example.

Comment: Lets try to keep in mind that English is not everyone's primary language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is in java. just to give you an Example

Base class has an exception on the constructor.

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

The child class extending the base class but if you create an object of it it will give u an exception.

```
public class MainClass extends BaseClass 
{
    public MainClass()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass c = new MainClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: This make it impossible to create instance of this. And how would you use this?

Comment: this is the closest solution am looking for, but i recommend if it is more related to design than throwing an exception.

as more explanation, i want to force classes to look like utility classes, they should be stateless and all of their methods &  attributes static, exactly like Math class, now i believe i can not force the methods or the attributes to be static, but at least i want to make sure that these classes are unable to be instantiated.

in short, consider that Math class & another class with the same design, how can i push these classes to be stateless by inheriting a base class?

Comment: You can't.  Base classes can't dictate what their descendants cannot do, they can only dictate what their descendants must do.  You can define an extremely rigid interface but IF you allow inheritance then you can't stop someone else from adding on additional functionality via polymorphism.

Comment: mmmm, then i think throwing exception will be my only solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want to seal your base class.

```
public sealed class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(){};
}



public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(){};
}
```

This will throw a compiler error because you cannot inherit from a sealed base.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify that in the baseclass, any deriving class is self responseable, if it wants to present the ability to be derived from, than you can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the base class as const - that way other classes cant extend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Please specify why you want to do this.